# Unable to display APIs in Azure Function App Swagger/OpenAPI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, swagger-ui

We have an Azure Func app hosted in **Linux Premium plan, private network, using only https**, but the Swagger UI cannot display APIs like below:
[image]

The settings below are set based on the link below, but the error above still occurs.

```
{
  "Values": {
    "OpenApi__ForceHttps": "true",
    "OpenApi__ForceHttp": "false",
    "OpenApi__HostNames": "/api"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi.md

**Settings**

.NET Core 3.x

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi 1.0

**Refs:**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi-core.md
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1933
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue recently caused by a new package reference added to my project: my API operations list suddently became empty, without any error when the swagger (or open API 3.0) file was generated.

The package causing this issue is `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`, with version `>= 3.0.32`. (issue with 3.0.32 and 3.0.33 which is the current latest version).

Note: I did not use this package directly as it is already a dependency used by other packages of my project, but it was upgraded to a version >= 3.0.32 when I referenced `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs` in version '5.0.1', see dependencies below:

[image]

The workaround I used in my case was to use version 5.0.0 (instead of 5.0.1) of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs`, which needs `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` in version >= 3.0.30 only